# Create dynamic HTML form using json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs-scope

Upon clicking the "get Form" **button** a request should be made to the form api and render the form using the information received in the response.Once the form is rendered, the user must be able to "SUBMIT FORM".And also the user should be allowed to repeat this process.
**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="JsonApp">
<div ng-controller="JsonCtrl" style="margin: 200px;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block" ng-click="JsonData()">GET FORM</button>
</div>
</body>
```

**Angular JavaScript**

```
app = angular.module('JsonApp', []);

app.controller('JsonCtrl', function ($scope,$http) { 
        console.log("*************Entered into getJSON(): *************");

    $scope.JsonData = function () {
        $http.get("https://randomform.herokuapp.com/")

            .then(function(response) {

                console.log("getJSON data is :: ", response.data);
            });
    };
```

**response.data:**(json format)

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Form_fields": [
            {
                "Autofill": "that other",
                "Component": "textinput",
                "Description": "competition hateth, because that will have to be chosen here",
                "Editable": false,
                "Label": "nothing to complain",
                "Required": true,
                "Validation": "^. + $"
            },
            {
                "Autoselect" :[
                    "Takes pains because"
                ],
                "Component": "radio",
                "Description": "are not those who are provident excepteur who",
                "Editable": false,
                "Label": "Duis him of them",
                "Options": [
                    "Some of these",
                    "Takes pains because"
                ],
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "Component": "textareas",
                "Description": "all the pains of rejecting it are lorem",
                "Editable": true,
                "Label": "pleasure as a",
                "Required": true,
                "Validation": "^ [a-zA-Z1-9 \\ s] + $"
            },
            {
                "Component": "select",
                "Description": "when an obstacle to cupidatat, however, believe that the life of a wise",
                "Editable": true,
                "Label": ", which is not cillum",
                "Options": [
                    "Pains explain",
                    "Itself",
                    "Them",
                    "Practice to come",
                    "They are"
                ],
                "Required": false
            },
            {
                "Component": "select",
                "Description": "there is something which is the order of things be dolor consequat",
                "Editable": true,
                "Label": "When the choice was accepted",
                "Options": [
                    "And",
                    "Not certain",
                    "We consider them",
                    "They pay labor"
                ],
                "Required": true
            },
            {
                "Component": "textareas",
                "Description": ", and that the choice of, and the duties",
                "Editable": true,
                "Label": "ecological soul",
                "Required": true,
                "Validation": "^ (. | \\ N) + $"
            }
        ],
        "Form_id": "2hUnEy6tqUXG",
        "FORM_NAME": "in order to make the distinction"
    },
    "Success": true
}
```

unable proceed, How to use json data for rendering HTML form.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an existing library for that.

A simple one is:
[Angular Dynamic Forms](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms)

More standard way is the [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) with this nice implementation [Angular Schema Form](http://schemaform.io/). See examples on how it works here [DEMO](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html)